# Any way to group Sheets source data in chunks?

Tags: google-sheets

I have some data that was set up poorly coming from Firebase Realtime Database. I will be updating the way the data is stored to make it easier to work with in the future, but for the data that exists I'd like to find a way to make it readable for a report. The data is coming in from the Realtime Database API into Google sheets, and it looks like this right now:

```
10/01/2020 abc123 Email | 10/01/2020 abc123 Status | 10/01/2020 abc123 Time | 10/01/2020 def456 Email | 10/01/2020 def456 Status | 10/01/2020 def456 Time
fake@email.com            Clocking In                12:10:50                 fake@email.com    --------Clocking Out    -----------15:16:53 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

I did my best to get format that like a table, hopefully it gets the point across (the hyphens were necessary to keep formatting).

Anyway, the object with headers like "Date *random letters and numbers for id* Field". Is there any way to group it more so it's like:

```
ID          | Email          | Status      | Time
Date abc123 | fake@email.com | Clocking In | 12:10:50
Date def456 | fake@email.com | Clocking Out | 15:16:53
```

I've got hundreds of these, so I'm hoping to find a way to automate it and make this data readable for other people

Comment: @Calculuswhiz A script would be fine. This will be a one time data-dump before changing how the data is stored so I won't need to keep something up-to-date or run it frequently

Comment: If you include a link to an editable sheet with say 5 or 6 rows of fake, (But structurally realistic data) I think i can show you how to do it.

Comment: @MattKing Here's a link to an editable sheet with 6 'entries'. If you are able to help that would be great! Thanks
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wx9L_Lk3Zc7mM3Ufd1uWkAW9L_GvCgtUInw3D4g_0zM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @CaseSilva So does the API always only pull in TWO rows like that? I assume there can be Many many columns, nut only two rows?

Comment: That's right, that's how it pulls it in. Many many columns, but only ever two rows.

Answer (score 2):

On a new tab called MK.Help in the sample sheet you provided, This formula will grab ONLY every 3rd column and transposes it to show the email addresses.

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet1!2:2,MOD(COLUMN(Sheet1!2:2),3)=1))
```

Similarly, this one will grab every third, but a starting in a different place to grab the In/Out.

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet1!2:2,MOD(COLUMN(Sheet1!2:2),3)=2))
```

This one will do the same for the Times, but it first Adds the date to it so that you can get a full timestamp.  It uses some text manipulation functions, specifically LEFT() to only grab the data from each row necessary to construct a proper timestamp

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(IFERROR(1/(1/(LEFT(Sheet1!1:1,16)&LEFT(Sheet1!2:2,8)))),MOD(COLUMN(Sheet1!2:2),3)=0))
```